# Hibernate + mariadb-java-client + mysql syntax error after rewriteBatchedStatements=true

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mariadb

I wanted to improve performance by batching inserts. Based on internet, I need to have rewriteBatchedStatements=true as part of the connection string. Without having that everything works fine, but after adding that I get errors.

(error is below, removed table/field names from the log, one of them is `value`, because I was debugging if the reason is reserved words, another is `id`, others are not reserverd words)

I have tried with hibernate.dialect as org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect/MySQL5Dialect/MySQL5InnoDBDialect. Not sure what to try next, therefore making this question.

> Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values (2, '2016-01-21 16:18:42.82', '2016-01-21 16:18:42.82', 2157838336, NULL,' at line 1
>   Query is:
>   insert into TABLENAME (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5, FIELD6) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), parameters : [1,'2016-01-21 16:18:42.817','2016-01-21 16:18:42.817',2157838336,NULL,223678]
>       at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:475) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.3.4.jar:?]
>       at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.result(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:396) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.3.4.jar:?]
>       at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:360) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.3.4.jar:?]
>       at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:320) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.3.4.jar:?]
>       at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeBatch(MariaDbStatement.java:1236) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.3.4.jar:?]
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:2544) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:484) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       ... 9 more

Versions:
hibernate 4.3.11.Final, c3p0 0.9.5.1, mariadb-java-client 1.3.4, mysql 5.6.21

EDIT: HA!, I was able to see the complete query by setting a breakpoint in AbstractQueryProtocol and checking the queriesObj field in MasterProtocol earlier in the stack trace. Will analyze them, probably the error makes more sense because now I see all inserts.

EDIT2: Hmm, the inserts look ok to me when they are in the array of queries. Not sure if this part of mariadb-java-client org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.packet.send.SendTextQueryPacket line 120-> has a bug?

```
                queries.get(0).writeFirstRewritePart(stream);
                int lastPartLength = queries.get(0).writeLastRewritePartLength();
                for (int i = 1; i < queries.size(); i++) {
                    if (pos.checkRewritableLength(queries.get(i).writeToRewritablePartLength(rewriteOffset) + lastPartLength)) {
                        queries.get(i).writeToRewritablePart(stream, rewriteOffset);
                        queryNumberSend++;
                    }
                }
                queries.get(0).writeLastRewritePart(stream);
```

EDIT3: Made own build of mariadb client with debug information, it seems the query is:

insert into TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5,FIELD6) values (the 6 values), (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5,FIELD6) values (6 another values), (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5,FIELD6) values (6 values), and so on.. 
To my knowledge the correct form would be 
insert into TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5,FIELD6) values (the 6 values), (another set of values), (another set of values)

Comment: `INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (1,2), (4,5), (7,8), ...` -- Do not repeat the list of column _names_.

Comment: I am aware of that. The X inserts are generated by hibernate and mariadb jdbc driver should combine the X inserts as one you described when rewriteBatchedStatements=true is in the connection string, however it would seem to be that it is not doing that.

Comment: <snide-opinion>Sorry, 3rd party software sometimes gets in the way.</snide-opinion>